# of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray a

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

> hi sir i have seen the whole stack overflow but did not found aswer please help me i am getting json data from api and but i am not able to get few items from this i am getting this error many times. if there is any question or solution that i missed then please help me to solve please..

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: BUFFER" + reader.read());
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
                Log.e(TAG, "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: length " + line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {
        super.onPostExecute(result1);
        String result = result1.toString();
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + result);

        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jObject.getString("name");
                Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: ");

            } // End Loop
            Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute: jsion " + jArray.length());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

> here is the calling function of that with api

```
        new JsonTask().execute("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols");
```

Comment: i want to get only name and symbol for each item please help me any body..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: sir problem is that api gives only json data not with some response like as shown "post" etc otherwise i will solve this

Comment: "posts": [
        {
            "post_id": "123456789012_123456789012",
            "actor_id": "1234567890",
            "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/photo.jpg",
            "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
            "message": "Sounds cool. Can't wait to see it!",
            "likesCount": "2",
            "comments": [],
            "timeOfPost": "1234567890"
        }
    ]

Comment: api dont return like that

Answer (score 2):

https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols returns a flat JSONArray with 9290 JSONObjects.

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, it runs fine on my end - the only thing I would change is remove the need for a StringBuffer, and you don't need to append "\n".. JSON reads as a single line.

```
 String line = "";
 String returned = "";
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      returned = line;
 }
 return returned;
```

You are saying you are missing some data - that is because the returned data has missing items.  You can see this by putting the full JSONArray return string into a notepad++ or something else that can easily format the array for you, you will see that some "name" are missing for some of the JSONObjects..

for example -
object number 9241

```
symbol : ZIONP
name :
date : 2020-11-09
isEnabled : true
type : N/A
iexId : 7674
```

You are trying to get the name, you won't get the name - the data isn't there to get.

Comment: sir issue comes when i want to read get single item in post execute

Comment: please help me in post execute to read other data as symbol only from the jsonArray of objects. i upvoted you because you understands me and give me time and i am thankful to you for this

Comment: change  String name = jObject.getString("name"); to  String name = jObject.optString("name"); - then you can check if the name is blank, if so, then you can jObject.getString("symbol");

Comment: sir sorry disturbing you but getting this error in catch pase of post execute        >>>>>>>>onPostExecute Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"symbol":"A","name":"AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES INC","date":"2020-11-10","isEnabled":true,"type":"N\/A","iexId":"2"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: did you update your code to remove the StringBuffer and not add "\n" to the line?

Comment: yes sir i added but same,actually sir error comes because of this dont know why   >>  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          if i comment this then error gone